# Connection to the DataBase lost after X seconds of inactivity

Tags: java, mysql

I have this error after 20-30 minutes of inactivity

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure 
The last packet successfully received from the server was 2.383.932 milliseconds ago.
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 21.351 milliseconds ago.
```

I have checked Data Base options,but they are ok
mysql>  show session variables like '%timeout%';

```
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| connect_timeout            | 10    |
| delayed_insert_timeout     | 300   |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout   | 50    |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF   |
| interactive_timeout        | 28800 |
| net_read_timeout           | 30    |
| net_write_timeout          | 60    |
| slave_net_timeout          | 3600  |
| table_lock_wait_timeout    | 50    |
| wait_timeout               | 28800 |
+----------------------------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

mysql> show global variables like '%timeoout%';

```
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| connect_timeout            | 10    |
| delayed_insert_timeout     | 300   |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout   | 50    |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF   |
| interactive_timeout        | 28800 |
| net_read_timeout           | 30    |
| net_write_timeout          | 60    |
| slave_net_timeout          | 3600  |
| table_lock_wait_timeout    | 50    |
| wait_timeout               | 28800 |
+----------------------------+-------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Connection class:

```
public class ConnectionDB {
    Connection con;
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://XXXXXXXXXX:3306/";
    String nomeutente = "XXXXXXX";
    String password = "XXXXXXXX";
    String nomedatabase = "XXXXXX";
    public Boolean ok = false;
    public Connection connect(){            
            try {
                Class.forName(driver);
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+nomedatabase,nomeutente,password);
                ok = true;
                return con;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException   e) {
                new ErrorLog();
                e.printStackTrace();
                ok = false;
                return null;
            }       
    }
}
```